# How to delete each DOM element separately

Tags: javascript

I have a button that creates two input fields on click. They also generate a font awesome trash icon and when the user clicks on the icon the two fields must get deleted. Currently my code deletes all inputs when clicking on the font awesome icon, how can I make so that only those two that belong to the icon get deleted instead of all? Here is my attempt:

```
  createNewPricedRoundShareholder() {
      var newPlatformNameInputContainer = document.getElementById(
        "round-shareholder-container"
      );

      const newPlatformNameInput = document.createElement("input");
      newPlatformNameInput.classList.add("form-control");
      newPlatformNameInput.classList.add("input");
      newPlatformNameInput.classList.add("dynamic-input");
      newPlatformNameInput.placeholder = "Username";
      newPlatformNameInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
      newPlatformNameInput.setAttribute("name", "username");

      newPlatformNameInputContainer.appendChild(newPlatformNameInput);

      var secondContainer = document.getElementById(
        "round-investment-container"
      );

      const newInitialOptionsPool = document.createElement("input");
      newInitialOptionsPool.classList.add("form-control");
      newInitialOptionsPool.classList.add("input");
      newInitialOptionsPool.classList.add("dynamic-input");
      newInitialOptionsPool.placeholder = "Investment";
      newInitialOptionsPool.name = "investment";
      newInitialOptionsPool.setAttribute("type", "text");
      newInitialOptionsPool.setAttribute("name", "investment");
      secondContainer.appendChild(newInitialOptionsPool);
      secondContainer.innerHTML += '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';

      document.querySelectorAll(".fa-trash").forEach( 
      function(el){
           el.addEventListener('click', function() {
                  var investmentInput = document.querySelector("#round-shareholder-container");
        investmentInput.parentNode.removeChild(investmentInput);

        var usernameInput = document.querySelector("#round-investment-container");
        usernameInput.parentNode.removeChild(usernameInput)
           })
      }
)
```

I also tried by getting each input target like that:

```
var A = el.target.parentNode;
A.removeChild(A);
```

That still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the input and delete button via a wrapper and then delete the current node whenever user clicks on the delete button.
I have create a demo, Check

```js
const mainParent = document.getElementById('main-parent');
var index = 0;

function addButtonRows() {
  const newPlatformNameInput1 = document.createElement("input");
  newPlatformNameInput1.id = index + '_first';
  newPlatformNameInput1.value = index;
  const newPlatformNameInput2 = document.createElement("input");
  newPlatformNameInput2.id = index + '_second';
  newPlatformNameInput2.value = index;
  const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.innerText = 'delete';
  const wrapperParent = document.createElement('div');
  wrapperParent.id = index + '_parent';
  wrapperParent.appendChild(newPlatformNameInput1);
  wrapperParent.appendChild(newPlatformNameInput2);
  wrapperParent.appendChild(deleteButton);
  mainParent.appendChild(wrapperParent);
  index++;
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    removeCurrentRow(event);
  });
}

function removeCurrentRow(event) {
  const parent = event.target.parentNode;
  const length = parent.childNodes.length;
  parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
}

const addButton = document.getElementById('add');
addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  addButtonRows();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main-parent"></div>
  <button id="add">Add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need some kind of identifies to separate each row of inputs and trash icon with other rows. when the user clicks on the trash icon you use that identifier to identify which row to delete.
In current code delete functionality there is same id for each input rows.

```
 createNewPricedRoundShareholder(index) {
      var newPlatformNameInputContainer = document.getElementById(
        "round-shareholder-container"
      );
      //index identifier for each row
      newPlatformNameInputContainer.classList.add(`${index}_thisform`);
      const newPlatformNameInput = document.createElement("input");
      newPlatformNameInput.classList.add("form-control");
      newPlatformNameInput.classList.add("input");
      
      newPlatformNameInput.classList.add("dynamic-input");
      newPlatformNameInput.placeholder = "Username";
      newPlatformNameInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
      newPlatformNameInput.setAttribute("name", "username");

      newPlatformNameInputContainer.appendChild(newPlatformNameInput);

      var secondContainer = document.getElementById(
        "round-investment-container"
      );

      const newInitialOptionsPool = document.createElement("input");
      newInitialOptionsPool.classList.add("form-control");
      newInitialOptionsPool.classList.add("input");
      newInitialOptionsPool.classList.add("dynamic-input");
      newInitialOptionsPool.placeholder = "Investment";
      newInitialOptionsPool.name = "investment";
      newInitialOptionsPool.setAttribute("type", "text");
      newInitialOptionsPool.setAttribute("name", "investment");
      secondContainer.appendChild(newInitialOptionsPool);
      secondContainer.innerHTML += '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
    secondContainer.onclick = function() {
                  var investmentInput = document.querySelector(`${index}_thisform`);
        investmentInput.parentNode.removeChild(investmentInput);
    //get the node with identifier and delete that node
            var usernameInput = document.querySelector(`${index}_thisform`);
            usernameInput.parentNode.removeChild(usernameInput)
               }
        }
```

Comment: Indeed, how can I add separate identifiers?

Comment: you can use dateTimestamp to generate indentifier or array index. i would prefer dateTimestamp @user14543107

Comment: I tried your code, but I get this error: ``` vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('[object MouseEvent]_thisform') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.
```

Comment: I am sorry, but i have only edited the post. The code is developed from @Abhishek. He can answer why the code doesn't work.

Comment: @user14543107 that code is just an example. Need to check for syntactical error and the environment you are executing.